# Spring Data JPA QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to create a controller that uses Spring Data QueryDSL.

My controller looks like this:

```
   @GetMapping("/playerAccount")
    public Iterable<PlayerAccount> getPlayerAccounts(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate predicate) {
        return repository.findAll(predicate);
    }
```

and my entity is (simplified for brevity)

```
@Entity
public class PlayerAccount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

When I call the GET /playerAccount API, I get the exception IllegalStateException "No primary or default constructor found for interface com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate" (thrown by org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor#createAttribute).

What could be wrong ?

Thanks

Edit:

my pom.xml contains

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I do not have @EnableSpringDataWebSupport but I must have an equivalent.

Comment: Can u paste the code for Predicate model. Predicate model need to be DAO and need to have a field annotated with @Id as primary key.

Comment: Please look at my edit.

Comment: The problem is clear from the log - your predicate class has no a default constructor.

Comment: Well I'm sorry but I don't understand what that means. What's my predicate class ? The class Predicate is not mine, it comes from com.querydsl.core.types

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind a few things before make it to work.

1. Specify below dependencies for query dsl support

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Add maven plugin for query class generation (in your case `com.fully.qualified.package.name.QPlayerAccount` will get generated)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

3. Enable Spring data web support by specifying `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` to your application's main class to support querydsl from web requests.
4. Provide meta information for `Pradicate` to get populated on the go

```
@GetMapping("/playerAccount")
public Iterable<PlayerAccount> getPlayerAccounts(@QuerydslPredicate(root = PlayerAccount.class) Predicate predicate) {
    return repository.findAll(predicate);
}
```

Now you are good to go to make request to use query dsl:
`GET /playerAccount` should return all the records
And while making call to `GET /playerAccount?name=Nick`

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Nick"
    }
]
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: I will double check but I already have all of that. Which part, if missing, would cause the exception that I got ?

Comment: @BobJI Most probably `@QuerydslPredicate(root = PlayerAccount.class) Predicate predicate` from controller's methods to capture predicate.

Comment: I've added that, but the problem is still here.

Comment: Did you fired `mvn clean install` before bringing the application up because it generates java classes during compilation?

Comment: Yes I did. I just noticed something weird, which relates to the error that is thrown "No primary or default constructor found for interface com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate" : The object QPlayerAccount that is generated does indeed lack a parameterless constructor. Is that expected?

Comment: Nope. It is not required. Can you provide more details in question? like pom.xml, Spring's main class and controller.

Comment: I already had the controller. I added the pom.xml extract, which is what you showed. I don't have the annotation you mentionned, but I must have an equivalent.